# how to make the objective value of primal program close to zero

Tags: optimization

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\min_{t_1, t_2 \in R} \quad & t_1t_2 + \frac{1}{t_1t_2^2}\\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & t_1, t_2 > 0\\
     \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

How do I make the objective value of the given primal program arbitrarily close to zero?
As $t_1$ and $t_2$ both have inverse ($\frac{1}{t_1}$ and $\frac{1}{t_2^2}$ respectively), can't make both terms go zero..

Answer (score 3):

Fix $t_2=a$, and consider minimising $at_1 + \frac{1}{a^2 t_1}$ for $t_1>0$. Verify its minimum is $\frac{2}{\sqrt{a}}$ at $t_1=\frac{1}{a^{3/2}}$. So for the solution $(t_1,t_2)=(\frac{1}{a^{3/2}}, a)$, the value of the function is $\frac{2}{\sqrt{a}}$. Now let $a\rightarrow \infty$.

For example, $(t_1, t_2)=(\frac{1}{100000^{1.5}}, 100000)$, the function value is $\approx 0.006324...$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the line $t_2 = \frac{1}{t_1^{2/3}}$

Now, if we let $t_1 \to 0$ along this line, then we can see that the value of the function is asymptotic to zero, since:

$$t_1t_2 + \frac{1}{t_1t_2^2} = t_1^{1/3} + t_1^{1/3} = 2t_1^{1/3}$$